# Create a google search bar in SharePoint Online website to search google

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to create a google search bar control on the main page of my SharePoint Online website. The bar should search the web through google.

Currently I have found stuff that requires SP Central Admin i.e they are for SP on-premise.

Is there any way of achieving this?

P.S. I do not want to convert my SP Search into a google search.

**EDIT:**

`<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="text" name="q" size="100"maxlength="255" value="" style="margin-left:130px; margin-top:45px"/>
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" />`

Above is my code that works. The only issue I am facing now is that when I use the page in a page viewer web part, it does not open anything as SP gives a security exception. I want it to open the search in a new page.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822927/how-can-i-add-a-google-search-box-to-my-website

Comment: If you update is what I think it is, it should be posted as an answer and not an edit

Comment: i am having issues with it. i cannot make it work inside a page viewer web part as it gives security exceptions in SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a textbox and a button, then use JavaScript to create a function that executes when the button is clicked. The function should take the contents of the textbox and pass them to Google using this syntax.

```
document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/#q=Query+From+My+Textbox"
```

Comment: i have made these changes (See my code in the question). I am using a page viewer content editor to show the page but when i click on the button to search , google does not open up in a new window but in the web part itself.
I would like it to open up in a new window.

Comment: Also it gives a security exception when it tries to open google